# How should I implement GET endpoint using asynchronous communication?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, microservices

I'm building a backend using RabbitMQ and Spring. My POST, UPDATE and DELETE endpoints works fine using my message broker (rabbitMQ).
However, I dont know how should I implement a GET endpoint using message broker. Is there any way for retrieving a database info for frontend using asynchronous communication?

Edit.: i have found the solution. You should clone the data from microservice X if you want to use it at microservice Y. Also, you have to keep this data updated sending it to Y everytime if change it at X.

Microsoft have some good stuff about microservices and it helped me a lot: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/communication-in-microservice-architecture

Comment: If you use postman, if you type in the URL for your requests along with the type of CRUD operation it is, you can get the code for it.

Comment: Just curious, are there any reasons why you need the 'get' endpoint to be asynchronous and why it should go via message broker?  If you need the API response for front-end, it should be a synchronous invocation of backend API directly and sending back the response to the front-end ?

Comment: Yep, @DinakaranSankaranarayan. I'm learning asynchronous communication and had a lot of trouble trying to understand how to make all my end-points full asynchronous using microservices communication. Well, I guess I shoudnt use it for GET. But if I dont, so I'll have coupling betwen services, dont I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using a request-response protocol (http) that implies synchronous communication with a asynchronous backend technology.

The problem is the following: with http you are using a thread of the server thread pool to execute the request and return the response but because you are using a message broker the thread that handles the request is not the same as the thread that recieve the response.

There are two possible solutions, if you want to continue using asynchronous communication to handle the queries (GETs) you have to use some protocol that not use a request-response model like SSE or WebSocket. Spring could handle SSe natively returning a Flux or Mono in your controller.

Other option is to make it synchronous and make a query call to database to get the result blocking the thread until you get the data

Comment: If I want full asynchronous communication betwen my microservices, aiming to reactive programming, how should I share data betwen than if I cant use http GET (due to synchronous nature of HTTP, of course)? Thats my biggest doubt.